# Is there a SQL script to restore constraints on a copied mysql database

Tags: mysql, constraints

When cloning a mysql database, if the "Add constraints" option is included, the cloning fails.

So I can recreate a large mysql database without the constraints, but I want an exact copy of the original database - including constraints.
Is there a way to copy the constraints from one database to another (the cloned database)?

I have searched and found nothing so far...

Comment: why does the clone fail with the constraints? how are you cloning it?

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin. I would guess that the generated script to clone the database includes the constraints directly after each table script - and some must reference tables not yet created by the script?

Comment: You need to get information about your constraints on tables from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table and then build a query by concatenating strings to create those. There may also be some internal function or so in MySQL that returns this for you so that you don't have to build it. I'm not familiar with MySQL, but that's how I'd do that in other DBMS. Maybe the problem lies inside cloning, and you are asking wrong question?

Comment: you can turn off foreign key checks while you run the import, then turn them back on, apparently there is also a checkbox in phpmyadmin to automatically add this to the export file (sorry, i avoid phpmyadmin religiously)

Comment: I am using the Copy Database feature of phpmyadmin. The only option here is to not "add constraints". My concern is that to truly clone the database, it must have those constraints reapplied. I need a simple way to generate a script to run against the cloned database in order to restore those constraints - the end result being an exactly cloned database.

Comment: If someone has a suggestion for a better overall method of managing mysql database, I am of course all ears! :-) Something that will do what I am asking about right the first time! :-)